# Stripejs props object is giving me an error message "Object is possibly null" when I try to use it to create a token ie props.stripe.createToken()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, stripe-payments

Inside my handleSubmit method in my checkoutForm component, I expected by having the interface of ReactStripeElements.InjectedStripeProps that Stripe would have the props available to be able to use createToken({}).
Below is my CheckoutForm component along with the Elements component nested in CheckoutForm on the first page.
I also have a StripeProvider with my apiKey on the second page below. StripeProvider is in App.tsx wrapped around everything in App.tsx. I'm wondering if the API key is able to give me that exact error message or am I missing anything else that's giving me that error.

```
import React from "react"
    import {
      injectStripe,
      ReactStripeElements,
      CardElement,
    } from "react-stripe-elements"
    
       interface IFormProps extends ReactStripeElements.InjectedStripeProps {}
    //Allow for props to be passed on to CheckoutForm from Stripe API wthout passing them in directly ourselves

    export const CheckoutForm = (props: IFormProps) => {
    
      const handleSubmit = async (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        try {
          let token = await props.stripe.createToken({name: name})
        } catch (e) {
          throw e
        }
      }
    
      return (
        <>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}> 
                <CardElement />
          </form>
        </>
      )
    }
    

    
    export default injectStripe(CheckoutForm)
```

/* --- 2nd Page Bellow --- */

```
import React from "react"
import { ThemeProvider } from "@material-ui/styles"
import theme from "./ui/Theme"
import { Route } from "react-router-dom"

import Shoppingcart from "./routes/shoppingcart/Shoppingcart"

import { Elements, StripeProvider } from "react-stripe-elements"

function App() {

  return (
    <>
      <StripeProvider apiKey="APIKEY_WOULD_BE_HERE">
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>

                <Elements>
                  <Route
                    exact
                    path="/shoppingcart"
                    component={() => (
                      <Shoppingcart
                      />
                    )}
                  />
                </Elements>

        </ThemeProvider>
      </StripeProvider>
    </>
  )
}

export default App
```

Comment: Where exactly are you getting that message?

Comment: Oops, I'm going to update that. I'm getting the message from inside the handlesubmit method, inside the try/catch block on the first page, CheckoutForm.tsx.

Comment: Ahh I see. Silly suggestion really, but what happens if you only try running the create token if props.stripe is not undefined?

Comment: I actually tried typing that in and felt 'guilty' for not exactly knowing why I'm getting that error but others from a tutorial wasn't for some reason. I'm going to try and see if that works all the way through with no issues.

Comment: I would assume that the stripe portion of your props is nullable. If the tutorial you were using was built with pure javascript, they wouldn't receive the same error message you're seeing but the problem would still sort of be there in the background. Hopefully everything works out just fine

Comment: It was actually built in TS in a quick tutorial. ( Doing that is pretty brutal I finished a course on Jest & Enzyme in pure JS while using TS :O  ) Yeah I'm going to try that and I'll let you know. Thanks!

Comment: Having a brief look at the TS definitions, it seems like `stripe` can be null: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react-stripe-elements/index.d.ts#L76 As to why that is the case... not really sure.